# How to create and use a list of unique dates of images in an ImageCollection GEE

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I am looking for a way to get a list of all dates where SENTINEL2 created an image in a specific ROI.
Due to the fact that my ROI may contain more than 1 image per date (several tiles) - I get a list with duplicated dates.
I have reduced the list by frequencyHistogram, but I need to use the list for a function that iterates on that list and extracts all the images from these dates. (Later on, I would like to extract SEN2 image from every date in the list and 5 SEN3 images from that specific date and 5 days ahead).

I have used the code described here: [Reference topic](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/284826/unique-list-of-image-dates-from-image-collection-in-google-earth-engine) but I cannot use the unique list because it contains the repetition of each date and my `ee.Filter.inList` is unable to cope with that.

So, for now I use the un-reduced list, but I get duplicated images.

This is my code [Link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/7427f2ac7b6a87d96ef71fe7eedf2091):

```
//Dates of Interest
var start = ee.Date("2014-10-01");
var finish = ee.Date("2020-01-01");

///--------------------- SENTINEL2 Collection ---------------------------------------///
var sen2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
.filterDate(start, finish)
.filterBounds(roi)
.map(function(image){
  return image
  .clipToCollection(roi)
  .updateMask(image.select('QA60').not())
})


// Year-Month-Day Extract function
function ymdList(imgcol){
    var iter_func = function(image, newlist){
        var date = ee.Number.parse(image.date().millis());
        newlist = ee.List(newlist);
        return ee.List(newlist.add(date).sort())
    };
    return imgcol.iterate(iter_func, ee.List([]));
}
// MilliSec Extract function
function millisec(imgcol){
    var iter_func = function(image, newlist){
        var date = ee.Number.parse(image.date().millis());
        newlist = ee.List(newlist);
        return ee.List(newlist.add(date).sort())
    };
    return imgcol.iterate(iter_func, ee.List([]));
}

var ymd = millisec(sen2)
var ymd_Hist = ee.List(ymd).reduce(ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram())

print("With histogram: ", ymd_Hist) //Need to figure out how to use this unique dates list
print("No histogram: ", ymd)


var allImagesInRange = sen2.filter(ee.Filter.inList("system:time_start", ymd))

print(allImagesInRange)
```

My questions:

1. Is there a way to reduce the list by key? So I will get only the unique dates?
2. How can I build another list that contains all the dates from the `unique dates` list and add (in addition to each one of the dates written there) 5 more dates? Let's say in time T I have a SEN2 image, I would like to add to the list T+1, T+2, T+3, T+4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a list of dates in your collection, you could use `aggregate_array`. Use `distinct` on a list to get only unique values. You can map over a list and `advance` a user defined period for each ee.Date.

```
// get all system:time_start in a list
var listMillis = ee.List(sen2.aggregate_array('system:time_start'));
var uniqueDates = listMillis.distinct();

// probably, you want to merge images at a single day, 
// thus simplify the datestamp
sen2 = sen2.map(function(image){
  return image.set('simpleDateMillis', ee.Date(image.date().format('YYYY-MM-dd')).millis())
});
var listMillisSimple = ee.List(sen2.aggregate_array('simpleDateMillis'));
var uniqueDatesSimple = listMillisSimple .distinct();

// make another list with (e.g.) 5 days added to all unique dates
var uniqueDatesAddDays = uniqueDatesSimple.map(function(date){
  return ee.Date(date).advance(5, 'day').millis();
});

print('original all/unique', listMillis, uniqueDates)
print('simplified all/unique', listMillis, uniqueDates)
print('unique Dates days added', uniqueDatesAddDays)
```

[link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/cfacbc759d5167b071061012c18046ff)

Comment: Thank you! Great answer. Works like a charm.

Comment: Sorry Kuik, after reviewing it once more, I see that I get the same results for ```simplified all/unique``` and ```unique Dates days added```. Both contain 362 elements for the time frame of 1-04-2017 to 1-1-2020 (it seems no dates were added).

Comment: Sorry, I mistakenly took `listMillis` instead of `listMillisSimple. See here for formatted dates so you can clearly see that dates are 5 days advanced. [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/26b64f95641ab16d2797fa9d80cdda71)

Comment: Wonderful,working now!