# MODIS monthly evapotranspitaion from Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to get a monthly time series of MODIS evaporation for a point with the script below, however the problem is that it gives me the weekly values for every month.
How can I modify this script to have only the average value of each month?

Script:

```
var geometry = /* color: #d63000 */ee.Geometry.Point([0, 0]);


var modisPET= ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD16A2");
var collection05=ee.ImageCollection(modisPET.filterDate('2006-01-01', '2018-12-31'));
var clipped05=collection05.mean().clip(geometry)
var TS5=Chart.image.seriesByRegion(collection05,geometry,ee.Reducer.mean

(),'ET',2000,'system:time_start').setOptions({title:'PETLong-TermTimeSeries',vAxis:{title:'PET'},});
print(TS5);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this answer: [How to create and use a list of unique dates of images in an ImageCollection GEE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/359540/how-to-create-and-use-a-list-of-unique-dates-of-images-in-an-imagecollection-gee?noredirect=1&lq=1) you can build a list with all unique months and then create a new monthly image collection:

```
var monthlyMean = uniqueDatesSimple.map(function(date){
  
  var monthStart = ee.Date(date)
  var monthEnd = ee.Date(date).advance(1, 'month').advance(-1,'day')
  
  var subset = collection05.filterDate(monthStart,monthEnd);
  
  
  return ee.Image(subset.mean()).copyProperties(subset.first());
});
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/f8d9242c7277939da0f66b4886001313

Comment: Thank you, indeed it works